# Clarification on definition of almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If a real valued random variable $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$, does it mean that for every $\epsilon > 0$ I can find an $N$ large enough such that for all $n \geq N$ we have:

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X| > \epsilon) = 0$$

I understand that the definition of almost sure convergence is: for all $\epsilon$:

$$\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|X_n-X| > \epsilon) = 0$$

But I want to make sure I am properly interpreting the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of almost sure convergence is $\mathbb{P}(X_n\to X)=1$, i.e at almost every point $\omega\in\Omega$ we have $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$.

For example, consider $\Omega=(0,1)$ with the Borel sigma algebra and the Lebesgue measure. Define $X_n(\omega)=\omega^n$. Then $X_n\to 0$ pointwise, and in particular almost surely. However, for $0<\epsilon<1$ we have:

$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-0|>\epsilon)=\mathbb{P}(\omega\in (0,1): \omega^n>\epsilon)=\mathbb{P}(\omega\in (0,1): \omega>\sqrt[n]{\epsilon})=1-\sqrt[n]{\epsilon}>0$

So your statement is false, the probability $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)$ might be positive for every $n$. However, this sequence of probabilities tends to $0$ when $n\to\infty$, this is because almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability.

Comment: Thank you, that's clear. The definition I've given felt stronger than a.s. convergence and now it's clear that it is.

Comment: I thought about this a bit more and I think my original statement was close to being true: If we define $N$ as a random variable that is dependent on the sequence $X_n$ rather than being chosen uniformly for all sequences then this can be true. In particular, $X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s. means that $|X_n - X| > \epsilon$ finitely many times, so there must be some $N$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) = 0$ for all $n \geq N$. But this definition does not seem very useful.